# Clarify the Impact Ajax Hash Navigation has on Search Engines and Non-Javascript visitors

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an existing site to which I am adding AJAX Hash navigation.  There are a couple situations that concern me.

I am using the onclick event of links to update the hash when appropriate:

My updateHash routine simply updates the hash to be #!Galleries/Colored-Pencil/71/1/

So - all links work for non-js visitors... the problems arrive when a hash-encoded link appears on an external site.

QUESTIONS

1)  Inbound Links... Say someone copies and pastes a hash encoded url (i.e. www.mysite.com/#!Galleries/Colored-Pencil/71/1/).  What can I possibly do for a non-javascript visitor that clicks the link?  It seems to me they would just end up at my default page.  The server won't know if the client has js enabled or anything about the requested hash.  I have to imagine there is no work-around for this... I would have to display the home page.  **Besides showing the default home page, is there any way to support non-javascript visitors that stumble upon a hash-encoded url?**

2)  Google... Since all of my urls are presented without the hashes (which are only used on a js click), I don't feel I need to implement Google navigation of hashed links (i.e. the ?_escaped_fragment_= scheme)... but what about external links that contain the hashed navigation?  I want the link juice to go to the 'normal url' (without hash-encoding).  **Should I handle '?_escaped_fragment_=' calls with a redirect to the non-encoded url?**  (doing so would also prevent duplicate content in Google's index)

I can think of ways to alleviate some of these issues (suggesting a permalink, trying to intercept 'copy' operation of url [not sure if possible or wise] and replace with desired url) - but I don't like these options and don't plan on investigating them... especially because the original problem would still need to be handled (being hash-encoded urls appearing on external web sites).

THANKS!

Comment: for newer browsers, you can use real urls instead of hashes. this works better because all your pages are, ahem, on the same page. history.pushState and onpopstate are your friends.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could make inbound links slightly better by adding a message to your home page that says "This site requires JavaScript to browse. I'm afraid only the home page can be loaded as long as JavaScript is turned off." And then remove that message using JavaScript if it's enabled. So no-JS visitors will at least see a warning that they can't visit the page they wanted.

Comment: @dandavis Hmmm.  It seems most of my visitors do support this... it would simplify things greatly to not let any #encoded urls getting out there.  I'm thinking that _only_ supporting this would be most ideal.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Yeah - I do support the non-encoded urls though.  It is just a problem for the first page that they hit via an encoded url (it would not be the page they were expecting).

Comment: @dandavis - even though your response didn't _really_ answer the original question - it definitely solved my problem by avoiding it completely!  I'd give it credit if I could, etc.   THANKS

Comment: you can use :target{display:block;} css to show an error message to non-js users, but you'll have to hard-code each possible hash into each html page because you can't generate it using javascript... personally, i would "ajax" it up transparently for those who can use pushState, and everyone else gets the static version. that's easy to code and provides all the best of SPA and SEO...